# What occurs in memory during these two examples?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, out-of-memory

With MinGW 4.6.2 (4.7.x does not seem to be the "latest" on sourceforge, so this one got installed)

```
void test(int *in)
{
    *in = 0;
}
int main()
{
    int dat;
    test(dat);
    return dat;
}
```

As you are probably aware this will give a warning in a c project.

`dirpath\fileName.c|8|warning: passing argument 1 of 'test' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`

And 2 errors in a c++ project.

`dirpath\fileName.cpp|8|error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]|`

`dirpath\fileName.cpp|1|error: initializing argument 1 of 'void test(int*)' [-fpermissive]|`

My question is, what exactly happens (in memory) during the two following scenarios, assume `-fpermissive` is enabled or compiled as a c program.

1. `dat` is uninitialized and the program proceeds (and no segmentation fault occurs).
2. `dat` is initialized to 42, and the program proceeds (and does seg-fault).

Why does leaving `dat` uninitialized lead to no seg-fault (perhaps by chance?) while case 2 causes a seg-fault (perhaps attempting to assign a value to a memory location)?

**Curiosity**: what does the `f` stand for in `-fpermissive`, flag perhaps? (seems redundant)

Comment: If there is something wrong with this question, please leave me a comment on how it can be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior as-is, so it's pointless to try to reason its behavior, but anyway...

The `test()` function expects a pointer to `int`. That pointer will be dereferenced and used to set the `int` it points to. However, you don't pass it a pointer to `int` but an uninitialized `int` - so it will try to interpret whatever garbage value is in that variable as  a memory address and then access the object behind it - and boom.

If you wanted to call the function correctly, you would need to write

```
test(&dat);
```

instead.

> what does the f stand for in `-fpermissive`, flag perhaps?

No, as far as I know, it stands for "feature". (But in the case of `-fpermissive`, I'd say it stands for "your code is ***f***..ked if you use this flag"...)

Comment: When the function call occurs, does it effectively do `in = &dat;`? If so, what exactly does `*in = 0;` mean to the computer?

Comment: Sometimes other software uses `-fpermissive` should I be skeptical towards them or if they are popular, consider them competent?

Comment: @Leonardo If you pass `dat` to the function, and not `&dat`, then no, it doesn't. The function call isn't magic - if you pass an `int`, then it will use the **value** (and not the address!) of that `int` and try to interpret it as a pointer. Of course that doesn't make sense and is erroneous.

Comment: I think I understand, by initializing `dat = 42;` I am saying `in = 42` and attempting to dereference a low memory address is unacceptable. Thanks.

Comment: @Leonardo Yes, that's what happens. If you write `dat = 42;`, then the function will try to do `*(int *)42 = 0;` and it 42 is not a valid memory address on your platform, then this will fail.

Answer (score 2):

As Warning says `passing argument 1 of 'test' makes pointer from integer`, you are trying to fetch something from a address which is value of passed integer.It may be anything.

when you are passing value 42, compiler is getting forced to fetch some value at address `42` which is not reserved for user and you are getting Segfault.By default compiler is assigning some value and later this values is becoming address, and somehow you are lucky that you do not get Segment fault with this.

Comment: I see, that seems to have hit my confusion on the spot but I just figured it out reading H2CO3's post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In c by default **pass by value** takes place.

```
void test(int *in)
{
   *in = 0;
}

test(dat); // passing value
```

here you are passing dat which is uninitialized. It will consider a **garbage value**. So you are trying to make the garabage value to act as a memory address in the test function. It is undefined behaviour. Instead you can try this.

```
test(&data);
```

Coming to your question.

```
Q. dat is uninitialized and the program proceeds (and no segmentation fault occurs).
A. This is an undefined behaviour because your are passing a garbage value. If your
   garbage value is a proper memory address then it will not cause segmentation error.
   If it is not proper, it will cause segmentaion error. So it happend at runtime 
   dynamically and can give either segmentation fault or can run.  

Q. dat is initialized to 42, and the program proceeds (and does seg-fault)
A. Here you have initialized dat to 42. By default c works on pass by value definition.
   So you are passing 42 to test. test will consider 42 as a memory location, which 
   is not a proper memory location so it cause segmentation error.
```